# Rails/Paperclip - Can't see uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a Rails 3 application which has an attachment model and uses Paperclip gem. Everything works fine on development environment but on production server we cannot access any of the images uploaded. The images are in the right folder where they are supposed to be but when I try to reach them on browser I simply get the 404 page.

The upload folder is located under public folder and called "uploads"

I can access this: "app_url/uploads/test.html" which I manually created to see if it works

But I cannot acces this: "app_url/uploads/test.jpg" which I upload within the application via Paperclip.

I can guess this has something to do with the server configuration but I'm not an expert and may need help about it.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've just realised that uploaded files belong to "nobody" and when I manually change the owner to "root" it seems to be working fine. So I need to find a way to tell Paperclip make the files belong to "root"

Comment: add code example please

Comment: I've just realised that uploaded files belong to "nobody" and when I manually change the owner to "root" it seems to be working fine. So I need to find a way to tell Paperclip make the files belong to "root"

Comment: Which user is your Rails app server running as? Which user is your web server running as? Why are you trying to access files via root instead of a valid, non-privileged user?

Comment: egrep -w --color=auto '^User|^Group' /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

returns 

User nobody
Group nobody

By default, uploaded images belong to "nobody" user but they throw 404, if I chown them to root, they can be seen in browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to have a web application being able to write files as root. File permissions are derived from the process writing the files. In case you're using Passenger, there's the concept of user switching:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerDefaultUser

Upon startup of your app, Passenger tries to figure out which user owns those files, and tries to switch it's application process to that user. In case it fails, "nobody" is the default.

Check your application permissions on the file level. You should have one user account per application on your server. The application (the directory and contents above the public directory) should be owned by this user. Files under public should be readable by others, so the webserver can pick them up, too.

Are you using Capistrano for deployment?

Comment: config.ru & environment.rb was owned by root and I made them belong to nobody, then restarted apache and my application, tried to upload files, success, the uploaded files are owned by nobody as it was before and still cannot see them on browser unless I manually chown them to belong to root. I'm not using Capistrano.

Comment: Your files and directories should not belong to root but to a non privileged user. As I wrote, Passenger picks up the user for the application process from the one owning `config.ru` (for Rack apps) or `config/environment.rb` (for Rails apps).